# Why does Android Studio give me warnings to add code that Android Studio already added automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-xml

As soon as I drag/drop a button from Palette into the XML file, Android Studio gives me the following error when I click on "Show Warnings and Errors":

```
Message: [I18N] Hardcoded string "Button", should use `@string` resource Suggested Fixes: 
- Extract string resource
- Suppress: Add tools:ignore="HardcodedText" attribute
```

Inside the Button code in Text the following Android Studios enters itself automatically when I dragged/dropped button into XML file:

```
android:text="Button"
```

Do I just always have to click "Suppress" choice because I don't know what they want me to change for "Extract String Resource" choice. Or is it asking me to change Android Studio's code that it sets itself automatically?

Comment: I'd stop worrying about it by not using the drag and drop GUI creator-  its about the least efficient way to work in Android.  Learn the XML language behind it and write your UIs in plain XML, you'll have fewer errors and get stuff done faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this instead of suppressing:

1. Add a String resource in `res/values/strings.xml`:

   `<string name="button_label">Button</string>`
2. Set the above resource as text for your `Button`:

   `android:text="@string/button_label"`

Comment: Why doesn't Android Studio just add the right code automatically instead of the wrong one?

Comment: I am not sure about the actual reasons behind it. They would have missed it. However, when you create a new project, the 'Hello World' text is in strings.xml file. Actually it's not right or wrong. It is a best practice to put the strings in strings.xml file. So that you can reuse the same string at multiple layouts, and it is needed for localizing your app to mulitple languages. Otherwise, both ways works without any problems.

Comment: "Hello World" is not in the strings.xml file. I only have the name of the file I gave in the strings.xml file.

Comment: It depends on the type of the project you choose in the New Project wizard.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I just downloaded Android Studio and learning it. It's a little different from Xcode where you can drag/drop buttons and no issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an Error, this is just Warning that say you should use string resources, but not hardcoded strings in your code. But you can use hadrdcoded Strings and all will work fine. 
Using String resources simplifies your life. For example when you want to localize your app. See screenshot. 
[using string resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRv9j.png)
You can set string res.  to `TextView.Text`, then create few `android resource directories` with names `values, values-ru, values-uk` etc. 
In this direcroties you should create file `strings.xml` for each.
and Override your string like

`<string name="message"> Message </string>` in `values` 
`<string name="message"> Сообщение </string>` in `values-ru` etc.

Now if you change your device language, from en to ru , in your app in `textView` will be written `"Сообщение"`

It is also useful in several other cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Message: [I18N] Hardcoded string "Button", should use `@string`
>   resource

Suggested Fixes:

- Extract string resource

You should always pick string from **string.xml** in **res/values/strings.xml**. It's not the right way to hard code the strings, putting it into the string.xml file helps for **localization** in future.

- Add tools:ignore="HardcodedText" attribute

When you use tools, it doesn't actually set the text to view, but it just shows you in preview window as how it visually appears, when you run the app, you won't the text added in tools.